# How to exchange small amount of bitcoin?

Tags: transactions, exchanges

Hi I have a little question could you tell which is the best method to exchange 2.27mBTC (18€) in euros or USD?

I registered on coinmama but the minimum for them is 50€ is there any other exchange services that could sell USD or EUR for my small amount of mbtc?

Comment: You could find a friend that wants to buy that amount of BTC, for your specified price. No exchange fees, no KYC risks. More generally, questions that are asking for service reviews are off-topic here. See: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 0):

The best and optimal method would be to avoid exchange since they will take their fees plus the fees taken by the miners that you gonna have to pay to send the coins to them on the blockchain, and also you gonna have to give them your personal information (KYC Know Your Costumer)

Exchanges are still the most simple, I suggest [Coinbase](https://www.coinbase.com/) who only require 2 euro of minimum deposit.

If you want a cheaper, savy way, more optimal and more bitcoin way of trading your bitcoin you could try [local bitcoin](https://localbitcoins.com/) which allow you to met other person willing to trade bitcoin in real life, or [Bisq](https://bisq.network/) which is a decentralized exchange software.

Answer (score 0):

Most exchanges offer you to withdraw funds without KYC, but the sum limit can vary. Worth just to research the conditions of every exchange.